# If I click outside the datepicker, it disappears

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using a datepicker in a modal popup using a trigger, but if I click outside, it will disappear. Can anyone solve my issue ? Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.datetimepickerInitialze').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('#daterange').trigger('click');
  });
  let isMobile = (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches) ? true : false;
  jQuery('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
    singleDatePicker: isMobile,
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a feature of the datepicker you are using. Can you link to the plugin's documentation? The answer is probably there.

Comment: https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: The [daterangepicker options](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) show no such setting as far as I see. You should use their bugtracker or support forum.

Comment: Most "popups" work this way - makes it easier to cancel/close the popup without having to use the keyboard to press esc.

Comment: I think you could write your own logic that will intercept the clicks and check if the datepicker is open or not, then cancel closing the modal if it is. You could use this: jQuery(window).Click({}). I havent tested it, but it is a way. Then use a global variable to check if the modal is open.